# Protection for M-BUS circuit?

Tags: protection, fuses, circuit-protection

From available sources, I've put together a functional M-BUS interface circuit, that allows a 5V MCU to communicate with an M-BUS enabled water meter. It works as intended, so no problem there. The one problem I have is that if the M-BUS cables are shorted by accident, the board WILL release all of its magic smoke...

I've tried to determine which of the transistors that are burning up, but it's really hard to tell... So, I am looking for input on how to protect the circuit, if the M-BUS cables short out...

[image: M-BUS Circuit]